# Как заблокировать ячейку в phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Я использую библиотеку PHPExcel.
Пробую заблокировать от редактирования ячейку вот так:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->protectCells('A8:A12', 'password')
```

Но ячейка не работает, редактировать всеровно можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью метода `setPassword`:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->protectCells('A8:A12', 'password');
$objPHPExcel->getProtection()->setPassword('mypassword');
```

Обновлено:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->protectCells('A2:B2')->getProtection()->setPassword('password')->setSheet(true);


$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('2.xlsx');
```

Comment: Проверил, не работает.

Comment: @Rider_BY попробуйте вот так (обновил ответ)